# Why md-autocomplete / mdInput throws type error

Tags: angular, typescript, web, single-page-application

Suddenly code stop working, and Im starting to catch throw

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this._inputContainer._elementRef')`

This message I get too, when I try to check [angular's example](https://material.angular.io/components/component/autocomplete) (I'm removing md-input-container, but all time, I didn't use it, and it worked normally. If I write md-input-container wrapper, all works correct, what happens?)

My code:

```
<input 
     mdInput 
     id="{{id}}"
     placeholder="{{inputPlaceholder}}" 
     value="{{value}}"
    [formControl]="inputControl"
    [mdAutocomplete]="auto">

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.userName">
      <img class="avatar" src="{{user.profilePicture}}">
      <span>@{{user.userName}}</span>
    </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>

constructor(private userInfoRepository: UserInfoRepository) {
   this.inputControl = new FormControl();
   this.inputControl
    .valueChanges
    .subscribe(value => {
      this
        .userInfoRepository
        .findUsers(value)
        .subscribe(usersResult => {
           this.users = usersResult
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you add Plunker example, please? I removed `<md-input-container></md-input-container>` from material2's example and it works fine.

See, https://plnkr.co/edit/VuJguKs3AB4luWgIzxHH

Comment: @Nehal https://pp.userapi.com/c636225/v636225308/2f4a1/_xj3ESgE7YY.jpg I have same problem in the plunker :C

Comment: Works fine for me [**here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1GnqrHa207oBFSUWGw9q?p=preview)